# How can I return the packets using bpf

Tags: c

I want to filter packets using bpf. I studied the bpf manual and write the filter. This is the last line of my filter:

```
BPF_STMT(BPF_LD+BPF_W+BPF_ABS, 16),
```

I loaded the ip packet length. Now I want to return `sizeof(struct ether_header)` plus the length abov.

How can I write this filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you load a word from your packet into the accumulator:

```
BPF_STMT(BPF_LD+BPF_W+BPF_ABS, 16),
```

First, you have to add the size of the ethernet header (14 bytes) to the accumulator:

```
BPF_STMT(BPF_ALU+BPF_ADD+BPF_K, 14),
```

and then, you return this value in the accumulator to get the data to userspace:

```
BPF_STMT(BPF_RET+BPF_A, 0)
```

*Note:*

If you mean to extract the IP total length, you have to load a *halfword* in your first statement (the ip total length is only a 16-bit value, so use **BPF_H** instead of **BPF_W**)

Comment: Thanks a lotttt. BPF_STMT has an operand section. What should I set for that?

Comment: @F.M Should be ignored, you can use 0

Comment: I think 0 means ignore the packet

Comment: @F.M The packet is ignored if you return 0. This would be the case, if you used `BPF_RET+BPF_K, 0`. But `BPF_RET+BPF_A, 0` does not return 0, but the content of the accumulator, which should be non-zero.